# create an Json file as an output from a ffmpeg command line

Tags: json, command-line, ffmpeg, output, h.264

I am trying to put the output I get from a ffmpeg command into a json file.
So I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i 2.y4m -i netflixboxing.y4m -lavfi "libvmaf=model_path=/usr/local/share/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl" -f null - > out.json
```

I get an empty json file. Do i have to specify which information I need in my json file?

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `log_path` and `log_format` options for this filter:

```
ffmpeg -i main.y4m -i reference.y4m -lavfi "libvmaf=model_path=/usr/local/share/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl:psnr=true:log_path=vmaflog.json:log_fmt=json" -f null -
```

In this example the log file is named `vmaflog.json`.

See [libvmaf filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf) for more info.

Comment: I get an error: Option 'log_format' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7ff9a2d04400] Error initializing filter 'libvmaf' with args 'model_path=/usr/local/share/model/vmaf_v0.6.1.pkl:log_path=vmaflog.json:log_format=json'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found

Comment: thank you it worked! can you please tell me how to get the output file for calculation psnr? I tried `ffmpeg -i netflix300kh264.mp4 -i netflixboxingHD.y4m -y -filter_complex psnr -f null - > out.json `

Comment: @ringola27 Add `psnr=true` to your command. See updated answer. Please refer to the documentation link in answer. So far it solved all of your questions.

Comment: its strange that the values are different. I use my command line and yours and i get different results. how come?

Comment: @ringola27 I'll make a guess that the two filters use different algorithms or methods to calculate PSNR, but I don't know. The psnr filter doesn't output json, so that's why i suggested libvmaf (and because you're already using libvmaf).

Comment: Is it possible to get the json output in a different way? as i tried for example?

Comment: @ringola27 No. You can redirect the stderr output and dump it into a file named `out.json`: `ffmpeg -i netflix300kh264.mp4 -i netflixboxingHD.y4m -y -filter_complex psnr -f null - 2> out.json`, but it won't have json formatting. Only certain filters support json.

Comment: It do not calculate psnr. I did nothing

Comment: @ringola27 Worked for me. There was no output because it was all redirected to `out.json`. Anyway, the main question of "how to create an Json file as an output from a ffmpeg command line"? has been answered (plus several others). If you have more questions you should post them as new, individual questions.

Comment: the problem is that the out.json file is empty;/ when you try the command line, you get a json file with content?

Comment: @ringola27 File is not empty for me (but as mentioned previously it is not actually json formatted). I'm using Linux.